# Gmail background-color does not work in HTML email

Tags: html, email, gmail, background-color

Aug 2023 - Does anyone have a simple example of creating an html email with a background color for the entire body that works in gmail?  I have looked everywhere and not one code examples work in gmail as of Aug 2023.  Hoping someone can share a small snippet from  to  that works in gmail as of Aug 2023.  I will be eternally grateful.

I have tried countless options and absolutely nothing works.

Comment: Where is the issue? What have you tried? What is not working as expected?

Comment: `background-color` does work in Gmail. Your problem must come from something else. Freel free to share your code for further help. https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background-color/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hope this will helpful to you: Gmail is already supported background-color property, For your knowledge I have created below one.

```html
<!-- width: calc((480px - 100%) * 480); -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:auto; max-width:600px; width: 100%; font-size: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 30px; text-align:center; background: #e1c18b; color: #643c33; line-height: 2;">Selfie with me</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/camera-mirror_446-19322773.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;" alt="Hero Image" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #322421;">
            <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="width: calc((480px - 100%) * 480); min-width: 50%; max-width: 100%;  font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; display: inline-block;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/young-hipster-woman-making-photos-with-vintage-film-camera-at-summer-field-women-lifestyle-concept_1150-1054.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" />
                        <p style="padding: 10px 0; margin: 0; text-align: justify; color: #f6e2c0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum praesentium ipsa vero consequuntur sunt porro vitae, a sed fuga debitis ratione, quas mollitia voluptate, ad voluptatum repellat voluptates! At, doloribus.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="width: calc((480px - 100%) * 480); min-width: 50%; max-width: 100%;  font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; display: inline-block;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/young-hipster-woman-making-photos-with-vintage-film-camera-at-summer-field-women-lifestyle-concept_1150-1054.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                        <p style="padding: 10px 0; margin: 0; text-align: justify; color: #f6e2c0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum praesentium ipsa vero consequuntur sunt porro vitae, a sed fuga debitis ratione, quas mollitia voluptate, ad voluptatum repellat voluptates! At, doloribus.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin: 0; padding: 10px; font-size: 20px; text-align:center; background: #564037; color: #ffffff;">
            Be a Selfie Expert
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```